# corosync-objctl: command not found

Tags: member, high-availability, totem

I installed corosync from apt repository in ubuntu 14.04.1 and configured two pc to setup the connection.

```
apt-get install corosync corosync-dev
```

The version of corosync is

```
corosync:
  Installed: 2.3.3-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.3.3-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.3.3-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

To check the members in ring, using

```
corosync-objctl | grep member
```

But `corosync-objctl: command not found`
what else package do i need to install? Anyone have idea?
Or any other ways to check the member in corosync ring?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i can use corosync-cmapctl | grep members to check membership, but why there is no corosync-objctl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`corosync-objctl` has been replaced with `corosync-cmapctl` in Corosync 2.x.x.